# can't get the escapes right

Tags: ansible, escaping

I have a DB tool that I want to call in ansible. The DB tool can take SQL commands passed in between quotes. The problem is that I cannot get the escapes right for this work.

The command would like this in a normal interactive way (as linuxuser)

```
dbtool -u DBUSER -p DBPWD "backup data using file ('/backup/path/prefi_')"
```

I tried something like this in ansible

```
tasks:
- name: something
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  shell: "runuser -l {{ linuxuser }} -c '/path/to/dbtool/dbtool -u DBUSER -p DBPWD \"backup data using file ('/backup/path/prefix_')\"'"
```

I tried escaping different ways, the dbtool just complains about the " or the ' one way or another.

Any hint would be appreciated.

PS: I cannot use become_user: {{ linuxuser }} because of other reasons.

PS2: dbtool only works as {{ linuxuser }} because of the various libraries in environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely be interested in the [`|quote` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) to get you out of shell quoting hell

```yaml
tasks:
- name: something
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  shell: runuser -l {{ linuxuser }} -c {{ my_command | quote }}
  vars:
    my_command: /path/to/dbtool/dbtool -u DBUSER -p DBPWD "backup data using file ('/backup/path/prefix_')"
```

Be aware that you don't need the outer `"` in your `shell:` scalar since it doesn't start with any yaml-special characters, and the same story for my `vars:` declaration for the same reason

*be aware: I don't have `runuser` to actually test that, but I believe it is accurate*